# How to assign Python list element? SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Tags: python

I read my file into list.

```
with open ('myf','r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
```

I can make my class instances, one by one.

```
p0 = Payload(lines[0])
p1 = PayLoad(lines[1])
```

My ideas is to automate this

```
p =str('p6_')
>>> for i in lines:
...     Payload(lines[i]) = p + str(i)
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

How to solve this assign problem?

Comment: What is `Payload(lines[i]) = p + str(i)` supposed to do? What is the point of `p + str(i)`? Do you just want something like `[Payload(line) for line in lines]`? Or even `list(map(Payload, lines))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to build a list, like this:

```py
p = [*map(Payload, lines)]
```

then you can access by index, like this:

```py
p[0],
p[6],
p[whatever_number_you_need]
```

Comment: `map(Payload, lines)` :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to assign the new `Payload` objects to variables named `pX`, where *X* is the line number. If that is the case:

```
for x in range(len(lines)):
    globals()['p%i' % x] = Payload(lines[x])
```

would do it, as `globals()` returns a dictionary where the key is the variable name and the value is the value of the variable. If I didn't understand it correctly, please tell me. Hope I can help you!